# Intellij: Force Spring Boot application to use classpath jars

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij 18.3 and have a multi-moduled Spring Boot application:

- module A
- module B (has a dependency on A)

I am then looking to run module B as a Spring Boot application within IntelliJ via the Run menu

However, when this application runs it uses module A's compiled classes from it's "out" directory

This works fine for 99% of cases but for my use-case I wish for the classes to be taken from the "build/libs" jar or the jar file deployed to Maven via the build.

Is there any way to force this in IntelliJ?

Comment: IMHO this should be the way IntelliJ does it. How did you import the Maven projects in the IntelliJ project ?

Comment: For the IDE to resolve dependency to a module sources rather than on library jar this module should be imported into IDE project as a Maven module and it's coordinate should match the coordinate of the dependency, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002826860/comments/360000332600